# Is it possible to make some of the bounded fields in a grid view invisible via CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I have a standard grid view, which contains a number of bounded fields and template fields, out of these I would like to make 4 columns invisible.

I know the css for this is `visibility:hidden;` but I do not know how to apply it to just these 4 columns, I have tried using the `ControlStyle-CssClass` property but it seems to apply the css to the whole table.

Is there a way to apply this css only to these 4 columns, also the plan is after I manage this is to write some Javascript for a button  to switch the visibility on and off, so if you could please use some CSS/tags etc which can be easily changed client side it would be a huge plus.

A example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gwFoo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"
                        Width="631px" OnRowDataBound="gwFoo_RowDataBound"
                        CssClass="customerDataTable" AllowSorting="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="type" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="id">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlNumber" runat="server">[hlNumber]</asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="product" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="product" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="startDate" HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="startDate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="endDate" HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="endDate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="isActive" HeaderText="Is Active ?" SortExpression="isActive" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="markedForActivation" HeaderText="Marked for Activation ?" SortExpression="markedForActivation" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status" />


                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parent Order" SortExpression="Foo">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlFoo" runat="server">[hlFoo]</asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parent Document" SortExpression="Foo">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlFoo" runat="server">[hlFoo]</asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="createdDate" HeaderText="Created Date" <itemstyle  Visible="false"></itemstyle> SortExpression="createdDate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="createdBy" HeaderText="Created By"  SortExpression="createdBy" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lastUpdated" HeaderText="Last Updated"  SortExpression="lastUpdated" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lastUpdatedBy" HeaderText="Last Updated By" SortExpression="lastUpdatedBy" />                



                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Code, please? It's much easier to answer a _code_ problem if we can see some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, in a way in which I can also switch the invissibility on and off from a button.

First I refactored the bounded fields I wanted to hide in this manner:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="createdBy" HeaderText="Created By"  SortExpression="createdBy" >
  <ItemStyle CssClass="fooClass"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```

The class fooClass is a empty css class, I used it only so that all the `<td> </td>` elements which are generated by the bounded field share a common class, thus allowing the `jquery` script I wrote bellow to hide or show them.

```
<script> $(".fooClass").hide(); </script>
// or 
<script> $(".fooClass").show(); </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

give the columns a class and set the class css to visiblity:hidden;

Comment: That's what I tried to do with `ControlStyle-CssClass`, it gave the whole table the class, I know it shouldn't do that but if you could be a little more specific about how I can give them a class.

Comment: to be specific and true i am not familiar with the asp but in normal html there are <td> defining the columns so i am just trying to say that you could name the <td> as <td class="something"> and create the css for something like .something{visibility:hidden;}

Comment: The problem is that asp tags generate html tags, if I write the html directly I would do that but then I lose the benefit of asp.net i.e the automated generation of html.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Visible="false"` will works
ie

```
<asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status"  />
```

Comment: This gives me the same problem, the whole grid view becomes invisible, it's obvious that your code should work yet there must be something else in my code which makes the whole table invisible.

Comment: It could be better for us to answer,if you post your codebehind